# List of which users are related to old users in sql (mysql)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this table in a db:

```
user
-id
-name
-role_id (related to a role-table)
```

**Example data:**

```
name of user1. id=1, role_id = 2, old_userid = 0
name of user2. id=2, role_id = 2, old_userid = 0
name of user3. id=3, role_id = 2, old_userid = 0
name of user4, id=4, role_id = 3, old_userid = 2
name of user5, id=5, role_id = 3, old_userid = 2
name of user6, id=6, role_id = 3, old_userid = 4
```

I can get this list of older user by doing this:

```
$this->db->select('u.name')->from('user u');      
$this->db->where('u.old_userid >', '0');
```

It would return

```
name of user4  
name of user5
name of user6
```

**But I want:**

```
name of user2[user4, user5] //user4 and user5 has older_userid as 2
name of user6[user4]        //user6 has older_userid as 4
```

`role_id=3` is the same as old users (user with role_id always has old_userid>0).

I'm kind of stuck here. Thinking of something like:

```
$this->db->select('u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(old_userid) AS uid')->from('user u');
$this->db->group_by('u.old_userid');
```

Help please someone.. :-)

I appreciate answers even in pure sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
$this->db
     ->select('o.name, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) AS `old_users`' ,FALSE)
     ->from('user u')
     ->join('user o','u.old_userid=o.id','LEFT')
     ->where('u.role_id',3)
     ->group_by('u.old_userid')
     ->get()
     ;
```

Note you need to pas FALSE in select's second parameter so it will be protected from additional back-ticks